# iOS view subviews doesn't recognize custom class members

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I subclass UIView and have an NSString member named imgName;
All views added to the superview are MyCustomView;

I do this:

```
NSArray *arr = [view subviews];

for (int x = 0; x < [arr count]; x++)
{
   MyCustomView *view = [arr objectAtIndex:x];
   NSString *imgName = view.imgName;  <-- Unrecognized selector

}
```

I really want access to that member.  If I kept a different running list of subviews image names it would be problematic because I would also have to maintain their positioning in the view hierarchy (as I want the view hierarchy as is with zIndexes).

How can I get the string from [view subviews]?

Comment: Can you post the class definition for `MyCustomView`, or more specifically, how you are declaring that member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double check that the subview is of the correct type.  You can perform that check with something like this:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < [arr count]; ++x )
{
    UIView *subView = [arr objectAtIndex:x];
    if ( [subView class] == [MyCustomView class] )
    {
        //Perform actions on the view as needed
    }
}
```

Odds are there is a subview that is not of your `MyCustomView` type and when it is trying to cast and access that member, it cannot because it is not the appropriate type.

EDIT:
You did mention that all of your subviews added are `MyCustomView`.  I personally wouldn't trust the iOS structure to not have subview already embedded in a `UIView`

Comment: This was just the check I needed. It does indeed look like iOS adds a default UIView in there somewhere.